# looping with SqlDataAdapter vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, sqldataadapter

I'm trying to loop according to the count of the gridview but it's giving me timeout at the second iteration.

Here's my code

```
  Try
        For i = 0 To Charges_GridView.Rows.Count - 2

            'check unit price
            'here is the error at the second iteration
            Dim quantity As String = "SELECT QUANTITY FROM [dbo].[SERVICEITEMCHARGES] WHERE SERVICEITEMFID ='" & txt_FID.Text & "' AND  FEESID = " & Charges_GridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & " AND CURRENCY = '" & Charges_GridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "'"
            Dim quantity_Adap As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(quantity, conn)
            Dim quantity_dt As New DataTable
            quantity_Adap.Fill(quantity_dt)

            If quantity_dt(0)(0) = 0 Then
                'Update ServiceItemCharges
                cmd.CommandText = "Update [dbo].[SERVICEITEMCHARGES] SET [AMOUNT] = " & Math.Ceiling(Charges_GridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value * 100) / 100 & ", UNIT_PRICE = 0 WHERE SERVICEITEMFID ='" & txt_FID.Text & "' AND  FEESID = " & Charges_GridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & " AND CURRENCY = '" & Charges_GridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "'"
                cmd.Connection = connection
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Else
                'Update ServiceItemCharges
                cmd.CommandText = "Update [dbo].[SERVICEITEMCHARGES] SET [AMOUNT] = " & Math.Ceiling(Charges_GridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value * 100) / 100 & ", UNIT_PRICE = " & (Math.Ceiling(Charges_GridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value * 100) / 100) / quantity_dt(0)(0) & " WHERE SERVICEITEMFID ='" & txt_FID.Text & "' AND  FEESID = " & Charges_GridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & " AND CURRENCY = '" & Charges_GridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "'"
                cmd.Connection = connection
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, why didnt you just do, `For Each item As GridViewRow In Charges_GridView.Rows`, instead of i = 0?

Comment: There are a few changes to make that would make troubleshooting easier.  1) Eliminate the data adapter and just get the value with .ExecuteScalar.  2) Use sql parameters instead of string concatenation.  3) As Danny said, iterate through the grid with FOR EACH.